# Publish custom facebook action on timeline as a Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-page, custom-action

I have created a custom object and custom action with Open Graph, and they have already been approved by facebook. I am able to publish this custom action as a user, but not as a page.

The steps I follow are:

1. The user authorize the app via the login dialog, granting the publish_actions permission
2. I exchange the short-lived user_access_token for a long-lived one.
3. I fetch https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=... and get the page_access_token
4. I try to publish a custom action on the page timeline on behalf of the page, without success, getting an enigmatic `OAuthException` with message "An unknown error has occurred."

The auth dialog is correctly asking all the permissions, and posting the same custom action on a user wall on behalf of the user works properly.

Is this a bug or I am missing something? Anyone managed to publish a custom action AS A PAGE?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you *can* undertake actions as a page – actions are ment to be undertaken by real people …

Comment: Is there something in the documentation explicitly saying this? Because as a page I can already publish links, images, etc., so there seems to be no reason why I should not be able to publish actions. But the error I get leads to think it is not currently possible...